# Set theory proof question with functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a function and let $C_1,C_2\subset A$
Prove that

$f(C_1\cap C_2)=f(C_1)\cap f(C_2) \leftrightarrow$ $f$ is injective

Attempt:

$(\leftarrow)$ Let $f(x)\in f(C_1\cap C_2)$. Then there exists $x\in C_1\cap C_2$ because $f$ is injective. So $x\in C_1$ and $x\in C_2$. So
$f(x)\in f(C_1)$ and $f(x)\in f(C_2)$. So $f(x)\in f(C_1)\cap f(C_2)$. Thus $f(C_1\cap C_2)=f(C_1)\cap f(C_2)$ I got to this but don't have an idea on how to prove the other direction..

Comment: What is the role of the $D_i$?

Comment: That was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those situations where we really, *really* shouldn't omit quantifiers. So lets state the claim as follows.

**Proposition.** Suppose $f:A \rightarrow B$ is a function. Then TFAE.

1. For all subsets $X$ and $Y$ of $A,$ we have $f(X \cap Y) = f(X) \cap f(Y).$
2. $f$ is injective.

*Proof.* The backward direction has been proved on this site about 100x already. So lets prove the forward direction. Let $f : A \rightarrow B$ denote a function satisfying Condition 1 (above), and consider fixed but arbitrary $a$ and $a'$ in $A$ with $f(a)=f(a')$. Now assume for a contradiction that $a \neq a'$. Then the first statement in the following list is true, and each statement in the list implies the next.

- $\{a\} \cap \{a'\} = \emptyset_A,$
- $f(\{a\} \cap \{a'\}) = f(\emptyset_A),$
- $f(\{a\}) \cap f(\{a'\}) = \emptyset_B,$
- $\{f(a)\} \cap \{f(a')\} = \emptyset_B$
- $f(a) \neq f(a').$

But this contradicts the earlier statement $f(a)=f(a')$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Did you say something was wrong in my proof? Could you point it out again?

Comment: @user143391, no worries. The "mistake" I saw was actually *my* mistake. Rereading it now, however, I can see another issue; your reasoning only allows us to conclude that $f(C_1∩C_2)$ is a *subset* of $f(C_1)∩f(C_2).$ So nothing is wrong per se, but the proof is only half complete!

Comment: Oh of course! Thank you for pointing it out. Need the double arrows.

Answer (score 2):

$\Leftarrow$:

If $f$ is injective, then $f(C_1) \cap f(C_2) = \{y: \exists x_1 \in C_1, x_2 \in C_2: f(x_1) = f(x_2) = y\} = \{y: \exists! x \in C_1 \cap C_2: f(x) = y\} = f(C_1 \cap C_2)$ where the second (and third) equality follows from $f$ being injective and thus $x_1 = x_2$.

$\Rightarrow$: Consider sets $C_1$ and $C_2$ consisting of single elements.

Comment: Could you explain more for the right direction? Please.. I am very stuck

Comment: See user18921's answer for that.